# Why does an "YYYY.MM" date converted with df['date'].astype(str).str[-2:] come out between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal

I have the following dataframe:

```
date    sea_temp_diff   wind_distance_diff  wind_speed_diff temp_diff   humidity_diff   current_distance_diff   current_speed_diff  month   year
0   2017.04 2.600000    20.000000   -4.000000   0.000000    0.000000    -90.000000  -1.000000e-01   04  2017
1   2017.05 -1.553333   8.666667    0.833333    -0.766667   0.000000    95.000000   -1.300000e-01   05  2017
2   2017.06 -1.551852   -10.370370  -1.888889   -0.888889   0.000000    179.629630  -2.851852e-01   06  2017
3   2017.07 -1.653571   -20.000000  -2.357143   -1.071429   0.000000    77.142857   -3.000000e-01   07  2017
4   2017.08 -1.287500   -8.333333   -1.916667   -1.166667   0.000000    88.333333   -2.041667e-01   08  2017
5   2017.09 -1.262500   3.333333    -1.375000   0.166667    615.833333  13.333333   -3.750000e-02   09  2017
6   2017.10 -0.809677   -146.451613 -161.548387 0.419355    -7.064516   -79.354839  -1.613645e+02   .1  2017
```

I generated this dataframe with:

```
australia_overview_clean['month'] = australia_overview_clean['date'].astype(str).str[-2:]
australia_overview_clean
```

For some reason though, instead of returning the '10' month, I get '0.1'. while it is mathematically identical to 10 or 0.10, I wouldn't mind finding a way to put 10 in its place instead. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Please fix your data snippet formatting. However, as your column `month` seems to have leading zeros, I would assume that `.1` (see last data row) is a typo and should be `01` (`.` is next to `0` on the numpad).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Iguananaut - You need to have the "date" column as `float` to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Note for the future: Try to write your question titles to be standalone enough that someone can identify the specific technical problem your question is about from the title _before reading the question body_. (I've tried to edit towards that end).

Comment: Yeah, the 01/02 format does seem to be causing the issue. And you're right that the .1 is indeed a typo, but it's actually 10 that I want as opposed to another 01.

Comment: Is it possible to read the column as string while loading the data in to the data frame? like:- read_csv('sample.csv', dtype={'date': object})

Comment: not_speshal helped me resolve this. Now what I'd like to do is get rid of all of the '-' symbols in the dataframe? What's the quickest way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your year and month from the date by splitting on "`.`".
`ljust` is used to make sure the date column is 7 characters long before splitting.

```
df[["year", "month"]] = df["date"].astype(str).str.ljust(7,"0").str.split(".", expand=True).astype(int)

>>> df[["date", "year", "month"]]
      date  year  month
0  2017.04  2017      4
1  2017.05  2017      5
2  2017.06  2017      6
3  2017.07  2017      7
4  2017.08  2017      8
5  2017.09  2017      9
6  2017.10  2017     10
```

Comment: Looks promising, except I'd like that 1 in row 6 to be 10 instead